# how to call function throw an array of pointers in C

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

The task is to draw triangles with star pattern.

1. each triangle has a separate function
2. function must call through an array of pointers.

I made triangle patterns function. I cant call the function from array of pointers. When I am trying to execute, couldn't be able to print a triangle.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
 
using namespace std;
 
void triangle1(int *array)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < *array  ; i++)
    {
    for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
     printf("*"); 
     }
     printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
 
void triangle2(int *array)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = *array ; i > 0; i--)
    {
     for (j = i; j >= 0; j--)
     {   
      printf("*");
      }
  printf("\n");
  }
  printf("\n");
}
 
void triangle3(int *array)
{
       for (int i = 0; i < *array  ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = *array; j >= i; j--)
            printf(" ");
       
        for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++)
            printf("*");
      
         printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
 
 int main()
{
    int SIZE = 0;
    int i;
    printf("Enter size of array\n");
    scanf_s("%i", &SIZE);
 
       int* array = new int(SIZE);
       int choice;
       void* fun[](int *) = { triangle1,triangle2,triangle3 };
 
       printf("choose a triangle\n");
       scanf_s("%i", &choice);
       
        i= (int)fun[choice];
        printf("%i", i);
 
    
}
```

Comment: Show the image you are trying to output.

Comment: `iostream` is not C, so I retagged to C++

Comment: `(int)fun[choice];` is definitely not how you call a function

Comment: @klutt It's more than that. In this code `using namespace std;` is the border line between C++ and C parts.

Comment: @Cem This is not C code. Stop tagging it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of code is so much easier with a typedef

```
typedef void (*func_ptr)(int*); // func_ptr is a function pointer


func_ptr fun[] = { triangle1, triangle2, triangle3 };


fun[choice](array);
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @klutt It illustrates the syntax necessary to define and use an array of function pointers. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Does it solve OP:s problem?